# Android 10 Requesting permissions and persistent permission on a Content URI

Tags: uri, android-10.0, scoped-storage

Good evening all. I have been stuck on this one a couple days. I have an android application which allows you to add images and displays them in a note. I just upgraded my phone to Android 10 and the new SAF rules seem to be getting me stuck. Previously in pre android 10 if an image was moved to another folder I did not have to request permissions on that URI again, the URI didn't change, and I would continue to have access to the Image. It appears that now the URI changes and I must request permissions on the new URI.

Also when transferring data from an old phone to a new phone I would like be able to maintain the images I have saved and not lose the references to this data.

Where I am at now:

I was previously just storing the content URI in Room. I believe I need to store the content URI as well as the display name. Then I can get the new Content URI by querying the MediaStore. From there I am having trouble asking permissions on the new content URI I have acquired. If I request persistentPermissions on this URI I just get a "no permissions exception". I have requested the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and can get a valid content Uri which my application can access

Is there an Action or am I able to request these permissions on a content URI? Is there a way to use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to open a specific content URI so the user may select the file again granting me permissions again? Better yet is there a way to use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to open a list of images from a list of content URI's I provide and allow the user to grant permissions on all of them again?

This is the code I am using to try and regain access to a moved (or reimported to new phone) contentUri (using a file name that is just hard-coded for now)

```
ni.myList.iterator().forEach { it ->
    
    val notExist = application.contentResolver.getType(Uri.parse(it.fileUri)) == null

    if(notExist){

        val projection = arrayOf(
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, //TODO store the new content uri and ask permissions for the image.
        )

        val selection = "${MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME} = ?"

        val selectionArgs = arrayOf("IMG_20201216_162211.jpg")

        val sortOrder = "${MediaStore.Images.Media._ID} DESC"

        var id = -1L

        getApplication<Application>().contentResolver.query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                sortOrder
        )?.use { cursor ->
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                id = cursor.getLong(0)
            }
        }

        if(id != -1L){
            val newContentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id)
            it.fileUri = newContentUri.toString()
            
     //application.contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(Uri.parse(newContentUri.toString()), Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
     //Above just throws Exception

            val intent = Intent().apply{
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, arrayListOf("image/*"))
                data = Uri.parse(newContentUri.toString())
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION) //This just opens it in image display app. No option to grant permissions
            }
            
            
/* This just opens Picker without the intended file
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply{
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, arrayListOf("image/*"))
                data = Uri.parse(newContentUri.toString())
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)
            }                               
*/                      

            mMainActivityHelper.startActivityForResult(intent, 10110)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow up on this one. There are just too many scenarios and differences in the versions of android. The only way I am able to truly have an image and not lose it is to make a copy of it in app-local storage. This is a big disappointment because it unnecessarily increases my apps size, but id rather a large app size then a lot of defects or explaining how to work things